# Euclidean algorithm and Multiplicative inverse in RSA Cryptosystem

Tags: computational-mathematics, euclidean-algorithm, multiplicative-function

I understand RSA Cryptosystem, the Euclidean algorithm, and mod, however, I can't seem to understand how to solve the following problem.

-Use Euclidean algorithm to compute the multiplicative inverse $s = r^{-1}\bmod (p − 1)(q − 1)$, where $r = 89$ and $p = 173$, $q = 103$.

So, I've found the equation for the multiplicative inverse ($89x + 17544y = 1$) and some GCD:

$\gcd(17544, 89)= 11 (197×89 +11) $

$11=17544-197×89$

$\gcd(89, 11)= 1 (8×11+1)$

$1= 89 -8×11$

- $1=89-8×11 \implies 1= ?$
  That is the part I'm confused about. I'm not sure with what I should substitute it with.

Answer (score 1):

It's important to be neat and methodical when performing the extended Euclidean algorithm, so you don't get tangled up. ;)

Your goal is to find an $x,y$ pair that satisfy
$$89x + 17544y = 1$$

You have calculated all the bits you need. You just need to replace the $11$ in
$$1=89-8×11$$
with
$$11=17544-197×89$$
Thus,
$$1=89-8×(17544-197×89)$$
which can easily be simplified.

Answer (score 0):

Use the *extended Euclidean algorithm* to obtain a direct answer, using the recursive relation $\:u_{n+1}=u_{n-1}-q_nr_n$:

\begin{array}{rrrr}
r_n &u_n&v_n &q_n \\\hline
17544&0&1 \\
89 &1&0&197 \\\hline
11&-197 &1 & 8 \\
1 & \color{red}{1577} &-8  \\
\hline
\end{array}